# Show $1$ is a persistent null state in $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1/2&1/2&0\\0&0&1\\\frac{1}{n+1}&0 &\frac{n}{n+1}\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

> A three-state time-inhomogeneous Markov chain has the transition matrix:
>   $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> \frac{1}{n+1} &0  &\frac{n}{n+1} & 
> \end{array} \right)$$
>   where $P(n)$ is the transition matrix at step $n$.

How do I show that state $1$ is a persistent null state? 
what are the first steps?

Comment: What have you tried? The crux of the matter (to show the "null" part) will be to show that $\mathbb E_3[T_1] = \infty$.

Comment: Don’t you mean $P(x_n=i\dots)=1$?

Comment: Can a Markov chain with a finite state space have any null persistent states at all?

Comment: @amd a time-homogenous one could not, of course, but I think it's fine for a time-inhomogeneous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For persistence I calculate $f_{ij}(n)$, the probability of returning to state $i$ for the **first time**, given we start in state $j$ in $n$ steps. This tells us:
$$ f_{11}(1) = \frac{1}{2}  $$ 
$$ f_{11}(2) = 0  $$
We move like $1 \to 2 \to 3$
$$ f_{11}(3) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot  \frac{1}{3+1}= \frac{1}{8} $$
We now traverse the chain like $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 3 \to 1$
$$ f_{11}(4) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{3+1}\frac{1}{4+1}  = \frac{12}{30}=\frac{2}{5}.  $$
We now traverse the chain like $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 3 \to 3 \to 1$
$$ f_{11}(5) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{3+1}\frac{4}{4+1}\frac{1}{5+1} =\frac{3 \cdot 4}{2\cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6}=\frac{3}{60}=\frac{1}{20}.  $$
Continuing in this manner we find for $k>2$ by cancellation of terms in the enumerator and denominator:
$$ f_{11}(k) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{3+1}\frac{4}{4+1} \dots \frac{k-2}{k-1}\frac{k-1}{k}\frac{1}{k+1}= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{k+1}  $$

---

We get by definition of persistence in my book (Grimmet and Stirzaker definition (1) on page 220):
$$ f_{11} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{11}(n)$$
If $f_{11}=1$ we know state $1$ is persistent. We will determine the sum by using the values from the previous section:
$$ f_{11}= \frac{1}{2} + 0 + \frac{3}{2}  \sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{k+1}$$  $$=\frac{1}{2} +  \frac{3}{2}  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{4}= \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{3}{2}\cdot 1 - 1=1. $$

Since by telescoping we know: $$S_n=
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}- \frac{1}{k+1} =1 - \frac{1}{n+1} $$
And thus $S_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

---

Now we know that state $1$ is persistent, we can also calculate the mean recurrence time for state $1$ (definition (7) page 222 of Grimmet and Stirzaker:
$$ \mu_1 := \sum_{k=1}^\infty k f_{11}(k)$$
This gives us:
$$ \mu_1 = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2} + 2 \cdot 0 + \frac{3}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \cdot  \frac{1}{k (k+1)} > \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1}=\infty $$
Which is a divergent minorant. By the comparison test the mean recurrence time is infinite and hence this state is null recurrent/persistent.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints for how to proceed, although I acknowledge that these may be unhelpful since I don't know what your background knowledge is:

**Persistence:** The limit of $P$ you mentioned in the comments is a bit of an oversimplification; the chain will never *actually* alternate between states 2 and 3 permanently. Try computing the probability that a chain started at state 3 will always make the choice to visit state 2 at every opportunity. (Or, consider the sum of the probabilities of the chain transitioning from state 3 to state 1 and use a Borel-Cantelli lemma.)

**"Null":** A path from state 3 to state 1 will always have the same structure: some whole number of interim visits to state 2 first, followed by eventually moving to state 1 (as you proved above). Find the probability of a path of that structure having length $2n + 1$, and use that formulation to compute the expected length of such a path and show that it is $\infty$.